# Separate padding values for checkbox and text inside CheckedTextView

Tags: android, android-layout, checkedtextview

Im trying to build my multiple choice layout according to latest material design guidelines with CheckedTextView widget. But I can't find the way to set left padding for checkbox and textview separately (16dp for icon, 72 for text). 
The most acceptable solution i could find is to use android:drawablePadding attribute but i think it is not quite right.
Is it possible to set padding values separately inside CheckedTextView?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:drawablePadding="36dp"/>
```

Comment: Post some code please, I might  be able to help out if you post the code.

Comment: Here is my Custom_Multiple_Selection.xml

Comment: Personally,I would approach this programmatically.Find the sources of CheckedTextView and modify them to your needs.If you don't wanna mess with code wrote by others, create your own widget.After all it's a textView and a checkbox...

Comment: Have you tried defining a custom drawable (layeredlistdrawable most likely) which wraps around the default android checklist? This way you can control how much padding you have on each side

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it work for me, add a "padding" property:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:background="@color/grey"
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this one: (This is under RelativeLayout)

<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
    android:checked="false" />

It will stay like this:

Layout:
   |                                  |
   | Text for checkedTextView:      V |
   |                                  |
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm late to the party, but just in case someone is looking for a solution, here is how I did it using the CheckBox widget:

```
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="56dp"/>
```

android:layout_marginStart="16dp" sets margin to both icon and text, while android:paddingStart="56dp" sets padding between text and icon.

Comment: Question is asked about `CheckedTextView`. Not `Checkbox`